# Why use std::swap instead of assignment for built-in types in a move assignment operator?

Tags: c++, data-structures, move-semantics

I'm a C++ newbie, and this is probably a stupid question to ask.

I'm reading a book *Data Structures and Algorithm Analysis in C++*, where the implementation of a user-defined **vector** class template was provided.

Here's a snippet of it

```
// Move Constructor
Vector(Vector&& source) noexcept
    : size(source.size), capacity(source.capacity), objects(source.objects)
{
    source.objects = nullptr;
    source.size = 0;
    source.capacity = 0;
}

// Move Assignment
Vector & operator= (Vector&& source) noexcept
{
    std::swap(size, source.size);
    std::swap(capacity, source.capacity);
    std::swap(objects, source.objects);

    return *this;
}
```

I figure some operations are redundant, here's my draft↓

```
// Move Constructor
Vector(Vector&& source) noexcept
    : size(source.size), capacity(source.capacity), objects(source.objects)
{
    source.objects = nullptr; // Forget the rest two integers
}

// Move Assignment
Vector & operator= (Vector&& source) noexcept
{
    size = source.size; // std::swap is unnecessary
    capacity = source.capacity;
    std::swap(objects, source.objects);

    return *this;
}
```

Why would the author use `std::swap` here? To my knowledge, `std::swap` is implemented using move semantics, which is introduced to fix smart pointers, not for basic data types.

`size` and `capacity` are merely integers, `std::swap` actually calls `std::move` and does the assignment three times, thus slowing down the performance since an ordinary assignment would do the same thing. Or is there any benefit of doing so?

Re:
Much obliged for the comments folks, I can understand that there is no penalty for using std::move, but swapping means three assignments, right? Can I just use a = operator instead?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248281/discussion-on-question-by-hyperionfrog-why-use-stdswap-instead-of-assignment-f).

Answer (score 4):

The author of this code makes the entirely reasonable assumption that the implementation has a decent implementation of `std::swap<size_t>`.

There are a number of reasons why this can be the case, but the two major reasons are:

1. The optimizer will likely put the involved variables in registers, making the swap effectively free. Compilers track which register holds which value; so you the compiler can swap its associated bookkeeping without swapping physical registers. This is a pure compile-time operation
2. If this wouldn't have worked, the library implementation can specialize `std::swap<size_t>` and other critical algorithms. You probably looked at the non-specialized template.

Comment: So here ```std::swap``` is more efficient than a "=" operator? Or equivalent?

Comment: @HyperionFrog the floor is that they are both 0 instructions long

Comment: @HyperionFrog Probably not, actually. At best they’re equivalent, but not always. I think this answer is miselading: `std::swap` *does* serve a semantic purpose beyond assignment here.

Answer (score 3):

I believe it might be possible to implement a vector-like class template such that the pointer data `objects` being `nullptr` and `size` and `capacity` being nonzero would be a valid vector state. However, this would bring significant overhead into almost all vector operations. Consider just a simple `push_back` (I appended underscore to the private member variables for clarity):

```
size_t size() const 
{
  return objects_ == nullptr ? 0 : size_;
}

size_t capacity() const
{
  return objects_ == nullptr ? 0 : capacity_;
}

void push_back(const T& value)
{
  if (size() == capacity()) // too much branching here
    // preform reallocation first
  ...
```

If we instead insist being all `objects`, `size`, and `capacity` in a consistent state, this would simply be:

```
void push_back(const T& value)
{
  if (size_ == capacity_) // no unnecessary branching here
  ...
```

Comment: @HyperionFrog The solution provided in the book seems to be a very trivial vector implementation. In real world, vectors are extremely complicated beasts. AFAIK, before C++20, there were discussions whether vectors are even implementable without ending up with undefined behavior ;)

Comment: Fyi, it's the requirement to return a pointer to an *array* of `T` in `std::vector<T>::data` that isn't possible in portable C++17 without breaking the requirements around element lifetimes. You need to be able to transmute a `T[old_size]` into a `T[new_size]` (in an allocation with `capacity > max(old_size, new_size)`). Allocating a `T[capacity]` isn't valid, because that adds the constraint that `T` be default constructible

Comment: @Caleth Moreover, even with default-constructible `T`, it would be inefficient, when `reserve(n)` would need to initialize `n` objects.